# Do the fields in string theory only live on the world line of the string?

Tags: string-theory, branes

Say for instance we have a $D0$ brane, and this $D0$ brane is charged under the KK field. Does the strength of the KK field only exist on the worldline of the $D0$ brane? Same goes for strings: do the charged SUGRA fields live on the world sheet of the string?

Or does the field strength of the $D0$ brane or string extend outwards in space (like the classic EM field generated by a charged particle)? My apologies if this seems confusing.

Comment: Fields such as gravity, the $B$ field etc live on spacetime, but they are “felt” by the worldsheet of the string because that’s how they enter the string action.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov yes so the the B field has a positive strength on the worldsheet of the string, or in the terms of D0 branes the RR field has a positive strength on the worldline of the D0. But does the fields positive strength extend over space time? Like how the strength of the EM field extends over space time for a charged particle?

Comment: You pull the fields back onto the worldvolume, don't you? So the natural resting place of the $B$ field for instance is $B_{\mu\nu}$ with spacetime indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in string theory aren't restricted to the worldvolume any more than the electromagnetic field is restricted to the worldline of a classical charged particle: they extend throughout spacetime. It pays to consider the coupling of a 1D particle to the background electromagnetic gauge potential: the action is augmented by the interaction term
$$
\int \mathrm{d}\tau\ A_\mu(X)\dot{X}^\mu
$$

which is precisely the [pull-back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)) of the gauge one-form $A_\mu\mathrm{d}x^\mu$ onto the worldline, though one does not immediately spot this. The same thing happens for the background fields in string theory, be it the Kalb-Ramond field or the graviton: while they naturally carry spacetime indices, they enter the string action/vertex operators through the pull-back of the spacetime field onto the worldvolume, and corresponding coupling terms are introduced into the Polyakov action. Here's an example for the Kalb-Ramond field:
$$
S_\text{int}=\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int\mathrm{d}^2\sigma\sqrt{g} \ i\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}B_{\mu\nu}(X)\partial_aX^\mu\partial_bX^\nu
$$
where the pullback is a lot more evident. Now consider the essentially analogous scenario where the D-branes act as sources for the RR-fields. The RR-fields/potentials are again defined on the spacetime, and the worldvolume of the Dp-branes can couple locally to the $(p+1)$-form background gauge potential, once again via the pullback (don't be misled by the terminology, the worldvolume of a Dp-brane is also $(p+1)$-dimensional). For simplicity, consider the electric coupling (in the absence of the mixing Kalb-Ramond field, to keep things simple):
$$
S_\text{int} = \frac{e_p}{(p+1)!}\int \mathrm{d}^{p+1}\sigma \ A_{\mu_1...\mu_{p+1}}\partial_0 X^{\mu_1}...\partial_p X^{\mu_{p+1}}
$$
<sup>[See e.g. Equation (6.54); Becker, Becker, Schwarz, *String Theory and M-Theory*]</sup>

When you see the dimensions of the gauge fields in the RR-sector of the theory under consideration, you can immediately determine which Dp-branes are allowed to carry the RR-charges via the electric and magnetic coupling. Accordingly, the Bianchi identity of the RR gauge fields is violated in the presence of the sources:
$$
\mathrm{d}G_{p}=0\longrightarrow\mathrm{d}G_{p}=\mathcal{J}_{p+1}
$$

Note that this the exterior derivative on the target spacetime. Similar to how a local charge source in electrodynamics modifies the field strength outside of its worldline due to the p-form Maxwell equation, the charged D-branes thus act as sources for the RR-field not just on the brane itself, but also in the bulk.

Comment: I'm trying to visualize this. We have a D0 brane that is charged under the RR field (or any D/M brane in 11D) . The RR field becomes excited/has positive strength due to the D0 brane. So is the RR field strength/excitation due to the D0 - only localized on the D0 brane or does the strength/excitation spread out in space?

Comment: Also, are the 11D fields (RR,KK, etc) quantized? Is there an exchange particle for them?

Comment: I meant to say KR sorry (KK is kaluza Klein which doesn’t apply here)

Comment: @Nick updated. Also your second follow-up question is not really related to this one, so I suggest perhaps asking a new question.

Comment: Yes thank you! I am going to post the other question in a separate post

Comment: See my new question

Comment: @Nick sure, it looks good. I might answer it later today :)